# PHPUnit 9 Support for using expectException() with PHPUnit\Framework\Error\Error is deprecated

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm updating phpunit from 7.5 to 9.5 and I'm encountering a warning message:

```
Support for using expectException() with PHPUnit\Framework\Error\Error is deprecated and will be removed in PHPUnit 10. Use expectError() instead.
```

with the following sample test:

```php
public function testFooErrorsOnBlankBar()
   {
        $this->expectException('InvalidArgumentException');
        My\Class::foo('', '123');
   }
```

Where `foo` has a required argument `bar`.

I *could* update this test to `expectErrorMessage` but then I'm asserting on the message (which would be something like `expected bar to be set`) and not the error *type*, which in my opinion is easier to read as a developer.

I'm probably missing something easy in [phpunit's docs](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html?highlight=expectError()#testing-php-errors-warnings-and-notices) but I'm new to php documentation in general. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The error message says to use `expectError()`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: `expectError` and `expectErrorMessageMatches` are *also* deprecated. Basically it seems expecting errors is being removed. I have not found an explanation as to why as yet, still looking... found it: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/5062. Well: no reasonable explanation (which is less good than it could be), but... well... now we know :-|

Answer (score 2):

https://thephp.cc/news/2020/02/migrating-to-phpunit-9

From what I found `expectException()` is supposed to catch all different types of errors i.e. deprecated, notice, warning and error. So the maintainers decided to have separate methods for each type i.e. `expectDeprecation()`, `expectNotice()`, `expectWarning()` and `expectError()`

It seems to me the maintainers do not intend `expectException()` to specify the type of error in the first place, knowing whether it is deprecated or notice or warning or error is all they want to know and I partly agree. Isn't able to catch error enough for most cases unless your code can throw different types of errors and you want to make sure that it throws the right type of error.

For your code `expectError()` should be enough.

```
public function testFooErrorsOnBlankBar()
{
    $this->expectError();
    My\Class::foo('', '123');
}
```

Comment: Except `expectError` is also deprecated :-/

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't the code instead be:

```
class FooClass extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
   public function testFooErrorsOnBlankBar()
   {
        $this->expectException(\InvalidArgumentException::class);
        My\Class::foo('', '123');
   }
}
```